# How to find which package certain command belongs to on CentOS? 

Tags: linux, command-line, centos, package-management

For example I can easily find locate command belongs to mlocate.i386 package.

```
yum search locate
mlocate.i386 : An utility for finding files by name
[mirror@home /]$ rpm -qa | grep locate
mlocate-0.15-1.el5.1

yum search updatedb
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, protectbase
0 packages excluded due to repository protections
=========================================== Matched: updatedb ===========================================
mlocate.i386 : An utility for finding files by name
```

But it's not so easy to find which package free command belongs to:

```
yum search free   // this command just returns too much informationy 
rpm -qa | grep free
freetype-2.2.1-31.el5_8.1   // obviously not the package by which free command is installed
```

So is there any convinent way to know which package a specific command belongs to on Linux?  For example CentOS or some other distributions

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Query the rpmdb.

```
rpm -qf $(which free)
```

Comment: why not use rpm -qf `which free`?

Comment: Either is fine. `$(...)` is habit for me.

Comment: The pipe way `which free | xargs rpm -qf`

Answer (score 28):

**Ubuntu / Debian** example to check the package of the `free` command:

```
dpkg -S $(which free)
```

Comment: this works only for installed packages. i found [here](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.fr/2014/05/identify-debianubuntu-package.html) something that works for non installed packages `$ dpkg -S */free$*`

Comment: @bobrobbob I am afraid that is not correct.  I tested with `dpkg -S */firefox$*` which gives multiple results on a server which has Firefox installed, none on a server without Firefox. I think it can't work because `dpkg` is a command operating on the locally installed packages. To find non installed packages you can go to https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any&keywords=firefox

Comment: oh my. you're right, sorry for that

Comment: If you get _dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern_ [try this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159001/how-to-find-the-package-that-installed-a-comand-if-dpkg-s-finds-no-path-beca/159002#159002): `dpkg -S "$(readlink -fn "$(which free)")"`.

Answer (score 11):

For CentOS, how about yum provides?

Use

```
which free
```

to find out where it is

For me it's at

/usr/bin/free

So then you can run

```
yum provides /usr/bin/free
```

and it will tell you which package has it

Comment: If ```the command``` was not installed or available in your centos, you could use ```yum provides <command>```, because ```which <command>``` will return ```not <command> in ...```

Answer (score 1):

For all red-hat based distributions you can use yum package management utility

```
yum provides `which free`
```

provides argument specifies which package provides certain feature or file.