# Which package contains the `most` command

Tags: linux, centos, yum, packages

I feel extremely dumb for asking this, but:

On CentOS, which package should I install to have the `most` command (a really nice pager)? A google search turns up way too many irrelevant results. A search in the yum database also turns up empty.

```
# yum search most
bzr-gtk.x86_64 : Bazaar plugin for GTK+ interfaces to most Bazaar operations
eggdrop.x86_64 : The world's most popular Open Source IRC bot
gkrellm-top.x86_64 : GKrellM plugin which shows 3 most CPU intensive processes
man.x86_64 : A set of documentation tools: man, apropos and whatis
qbzr.noarch : Bazaar plugin for Qt interface to most Bazaar operations
```

As a more general question: How would I search for an RPM which contains a specific executable or file?

*Note:* This is not a duplicate of [How to find which package certain command belongs to on CentOS?](https://superuser.com/questions/467186/how-to-find-which-package-certain-command-belongs-to-on-centos) , as this only talks about already installed packages.

Comment: `yum whatprovides '*/most'` would have been the command, but on RHEL 6, it returns no results.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/utilities/CentOS_6/x86_64/most-5.0.0a-3.1.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall most-5.0.0a-3.1.x86_64.rpm
```

(via [rpmsearch](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/24050032/dir/centos_6/com/most-5.0.0a-3.1.x86_64.rpm.html))

Comment: dear down-voter, add comment why this is not useful solution please

Comment: "sudo rpm -Uvh http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.i686.rpm" unavailable, I used your solution it works thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS and Redhat, the default repository is pretty limited. To get access to a lot more packages, you need to install EPEL and RPMForge.

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#How_can_I_install_the_packages_from_the_EPEL_software_repository.3F

To install them:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.i686.rpm
```

After that, you can simply install `most` by doing

```
sudo yum install most
```

The command to search for a package still remains `yum whatprovides */most`. After a long search, the answer appears:

```
most-4.10.2-1.2.el6.rf.x86_64 : Text viewer similar to more or less, but with additional capabilities
Repo        : rpmforge
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/most
```